# Error caused by : at com.example.AppName.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)

Tags: java, android

Please help me out. i have tried everything but unable to solve this. The emulator is Prompting "app name keeps stopping". My API level is 28. Thank You in advance.

### **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.testrun;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
    TextView txtslogan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSignIn = findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);

        txtslogan = findViewById(R.id.txtslogan);
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Pacifico.ttf");
        txtslogan.setTypeface(face);

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signIn = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SignIn.class);
                startActivity(signIn);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layam"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blurry"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/decs"
            android:src="@drawable/zomato_660_020218051156" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtslogan"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/txtslogan"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/btnSignUp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="4dp" />


        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/btnSignIn"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
            app:cornerRadius="5dp"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="4dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Logcat

```
2019-03-04 09:29:42.314 7873-7884/? E/example.testru: Failed to send jdwp-handshake response.: Broken pipe
2019-03-04 09:29:43.660 7873-7873/com.example.testrun E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testrun, PID: 7873
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testrun/com.example.testrun.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.testrun.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:482)
        at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
        at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.example.testrun.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

"at com.example.testrun.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)" - this line in logcat was in blue.

Comment: perhaps you should use `fbutton:`  in FButton attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug in the library you are using:

https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/issues/41

According to the comments of the issue, it is still not fixed.
But someone seems to have forked the library and fixed it.
So you should try to use this instead:

https://github.com/jd-alexander/android-flat-button

Comment: yes the library was causing the problem plus the sdk version was too low(15). thank you a lot for the help. wish u luck in all your wok.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with colors defoned for FBbutton in your layout xml.

```
Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5 at 
android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:482)
```

You should check those. Perhaps remove all color attributes first and then add one after the other to find out the culprit.

Comment: still not opening. this is showing-java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testrun/com.example.testrun.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39:

Comment: the line in .xml is - <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton